# How can I create a menu in the start menu for my program?

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, winapi, windows-7

This may be an easy question but I am not even sure of the terminology to search, so I have to ask. I want my program to have a menu when it is hovered over if it is pinned to the start menu. I am attaching a screenshot where windows powershell illustrates this function, and presents a list of tasks.

[image]

Other programs sometimes use this to list recently opened files, etc. I am sure this is standard enough that there is a tutorial on it somewhere, would someone mind pointing me to it, or explaining how to do this? I hope that it doesn't matter too much what language is used, but I am proficient in Delphi, C++, and C#.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must use the [`ICustomDestinationList.AddUserTasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, which is part of the [`Taskbar Extensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#tasks) introduced in Windows 7.

## UPDATE

Try this sample console app, run the code and move a shortcut of the app to the  start menu.  (this is just a sample snippet, so remember add the checks for the result of all the methods which return a `HResult` value)

```
program ProjectTasks;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  windows,
  ComObj,
  ShlObj,
  PropSys,
  ObjectArray;

const
  PKEY_TITLE : TPropertyKey = ( fmtID : '{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}'; pID : 2);

procedure CreateTaskList;
var
  LCustomDestinationList : ICustomDestinationList;
  pcMaxSlots : Cardinal;
  ppv : IObjectArray;
  poa : IObjectCollection;
  LTask : IShellLink;
  LPropertyStore : IPropertyStore;
  LTitle : TPropVariant;
  LTaskBarList : ITaskBarList;
  LTaskBarList3 : ITaskBarList3;
  hr : HRESULT;
begin
    LTaskBarList := CreateComObject(CLSID_TaskBarList) as ITaskBarList;
    hr := LTaskBarList.QueryInterface(IID_ITaskBarList3, LTaskBarList3);
    if hr <> S_OK then exit;


    LCustomDestinationList := CreateComObject(CLSID_DestinationList) as ICustomDestinationList;
    LCustomDestinationList.BeginList(pcMaxSlots, IID_IObjectArray, ppv);
    poa := CreateComObject(CLSID_EnumerableObjectCollection) as IObjectCollection;


    LTask := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink) as IShellLink;
    LTask.SetPath(pChar(ParamStr(0))); //set the  path to the exe
    LTask.SetDescription('This is a description sample');
    LTask.SetArguments(PChar('Bar'));
    LTask.SetIconLocation(PChar('Shell32.dll'),1);
    LPropertyStore := LTask as IPropertyStore;
    LTitle.vt := VT_LPWSTR;
    LTitle.pwszVal := PChar('This is the Task 1');
    LPropertyStore.SetValue(PKEY_Title,LTitle);
    LPropertyStore.Commit;
    poa.AddObject(LTask);

    LTask := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink) as IShellLink;
    LTask.SetPath(PChar(ParamStr(0))); //set the  path to the exe
    LTask.SetDescription('This is a description sample');
    LTask.SetArguments(PChar('Foo'));
    LTask.SetIconLocation(pChar('Shell32.dll'),1);
    LPropertyStore := LTask as IPropertyStore;
    LTitle.vt := VT_LPWSTR;
    LTitle.pwszVal := pChar('This is the Task 2');
    LPropertyStore.SetValue(PKEY_Title,LTitle);
    LPropertyStore.Commit;
    poa.AddObject(LTask);


    LCustomDestinationList.AddUserTasks(poa as IObjectArray);
    LCustomDestinationList.CommitList;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
       CreateTaskList;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

[image]

Comment: There's a good example of how to do this in C# [here](http://www.canofcode.co.uk/software/how-to-add-jumplists-to-a-c-application/).